# Magento 2 advanced search has problems matching on a product attribute that has spaces and slashes in it

Tags: magento2, advanced-search

I am finding that Magentos advanced search has problems matching on a product attribute that has spaces and slashes in it.
E.g.:

I have 1 product with an attribute with the string "ABC123 / DEF456 / GHI789"
But if I search for "ABC123 / DEF456 / GHI789" (in advanced search) it returns no results.

But if I update the products attribute to this:
"ABC123xDEF456xGHI789" (replacing spaces and slash with a single x)
it works correctly and returns the product.

Any ideas what is happening or if there might be a way around this? I thought about a plugin to examine the search string but not really sure what I would be looking for.

(Also I tried replacing the spaces and slashes with other symbols (comma, pipe etc) but I have found that it will only work if I use a letter).

Any ideas? Thanks

Magento 2.3.3

**EDIT**
I am using MySQL search

Comment: are you using MySQL or Elastic Search as catalog search engine?

Comment: Thanks @paj - I am using MySQL and have updated my question.

Comment: do you resolved this ?